# Have error "Invalid update: invalid number of rows" when I already updated the data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my code looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let IndexPaths = NSArray(array:[indexPath])

    let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = plistPath.appending("/ClassA.plist")
    self.listClasses.remove(at:indexPath.row)
    self.listClasses?.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: IndexPaths as! [IndexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

I know that if I did not update the data from my data source it would cause problems, so I added these two lines before I update my data in the TableView.

```
self.listClasses.remove(at:indexPath.row)
self.listClasses?.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)
```

But it still doesn't work. I still received this error

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Does anyone know why that happened?

Below is my code for TableView

```
@IBAction func Edit(_ sender: Any) {
    setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection     selection:Int) -> Int {
    return self.listClasses.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let row = indexPath.row

    let rowDict = self.listClasses[row] as! NSDictionary

    cell.textLabel?.text = rowDict["name"] as? String
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = plistPath.appending("/ClassA.plist")
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if (!(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)))
    {
        let bundle : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ClassA", ofType: "plist")!
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundle as String, toPath: path)
        }
        catch {
            NSLog("Error!")
        }
    }
    self.listClasses = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile:path)

    //set up the textfield
    self.txtField.isHidden = true
    self.txtField.delegate = self

}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated:true)
}
```

//update
Now I deleted "tableView.reloadData()"

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let IndexPaths = NSArray(array:[indexPath])

    let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = plistPath.appending("/ClassA.plist")
    self.listClasses.remove(at:indexPath.row)
    self.listClasses?.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: IndexPaths as! [IndexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: *either* call `reloadData` *or* call `deleteRows` not both.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried to remove one of them (in both ways), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, that is the fix for the code shown; Are you deleting the row somewhere else?  If you remove the `deleteRows`, leaving the `reloadData` and you *still* get that message then you are deleting somewhere else as `reloadData` will never cause that exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have:

```
tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: IndexPaths as! [IndexPath], with: .fade)
```

Never do both. Just do one or the other. In this case, preferably just do:

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: IndexPaths as! [IndexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: This method should be called between tableView.beginUpdates() and endUpdates(). Isn't?

Comment: @BhavukJain No, you only need to use `begin/endUpdate` if you make multiple calls to some combination of `delete/insert/reloadRows`.

Comment: @David The change I suggested will solve the problem. Did you delete the call to `reloadData`? What is the new error after removing that line of code?

Comment: Still the same thing. "'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)." I posted my new code on my question.

Comment: It makes no sense. You are clearly removing one object for `self.listClasses` and your `numberOfRowsInSection` is based on `self.listClasses`. As a sanity check, using the debugger, look at the number of objects in `self.listClasses` before and after the call to `self.listClasses.remove(at:indexPath.row)`. What do you see?

Comment: I added 3 breakpoints, one is when I originally load the data, one is before I removed the data in the function and one is after I removed the data. The result is the number of objects in self.listClasses before and after the call are all 6. It doesn't change. That is strange.

Comment: One thing I strongly suggest is to update all of your Swift 3 code to use only Swift classes. You have lots of references to `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Don't use those classes.

Comment: Ok. Now I am trying to convert my data to Array/Dictionary/String. Hope this will solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UITableView {
     var dataHasChanged: Bool {
        guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return false }
        let sections = dataSource.numberOfSections?(in: self) ?? 0
        if numberOfSections != sections { return true }

        for section in 0..<sections {
            if numberOfRows(inSection: section) != dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: section) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
 if tableView.dataHasChanged {
     tableView.reloadData()
 } else {
     // Do anything what you want here
     // tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
     // tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
 }
```